# Checking validation in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working with an MVC application.

My code lies like the following:-

```
if(//there are errors then display validation summary)
{
<div class="error">@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "There was an error!")<div>
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("FoundSimilarAccounts", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contactform" }))
{

}
```

I just want to know what can be the if condition.
I only want to display that when their would be an error or their is something in the validation summary.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect the [`IsValid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.isvalid%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) property of the `ModelState` of the `ViewData`:

```
@if(!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    <div class="error">@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "There was an error!")<div>
}
```